# Deleting a record from a Table through a Subform on another form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a form called Serch form which contains a subform called projects_subform and the subform is linked to a table called Projects.

Now I want to delete a record from the subform which will in effect delete the same record from the table. Please find below my code for the delete operation.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j699.jpg

Comment: There is no code given in your question, there's only an image. Please post your code here, and some explanation of the current problem.

Comment: Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
Dim strSQL As String
 
  Msg = "You are about to delete this record."
  Style = vbOKCancel + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton2
  Title = "Continue?"
  Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)
  If Response = vbOK Then
         
  Else
    MsgBox "No record deleted", vbOKOnly, "No changes made"
  End If
   
    CurrentDb.Execute "Delete * FROM [" & Projects & "] WHERE ProjectID=" & Me.Projects_subform.Form.ProjectID & ";"
      
   
    Me.Projects_subform.Form.Requery
        'End If
            'End If

End Sub

Comment: Please, do not poste your code as comment. Edit your question and add it. please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the *RecordsetClone*:

```
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click() 

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Msg = "You are about to delete this record." 
    Style = vbOKCancel + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton2 
    Title = "Continue?" 

    Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title) 
    If Response = vbOK Then
        Set rs = Me.Projects_subform.Form.RecordsetClone    
        rs.FindFirst "Bookmark = Me.Projects_subform.Form.Bookmark
        rs.Delete
    Else 
        MsgBox "No record deleted", vbOKOnly, "No changes made" 
    End If 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the record source (underlying table or query) is of type Dynaset and Allow Deletions property is "Yes", you can delete records on the form by selecting a record and clicking the Delete key on your keyboard ([Form Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Yq3K.png)).

Alternatively, you can select a record and click Delete in the Home menu bar at the top of the application ([Home bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4yOr.png)).